# DJI lightbridge 2 remote controller

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to develop a simulator using DJI lightbridge 2 remote controller .I  want to connect DJI Controller lightbride 2 remote controller with Android. I only want to read its control stick / buttons data and want to use in my Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe below link is what you need.
https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/RemoteController/DJIRemoteController_DJIRCHardwareState.html

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)